# SSRS - Show Average percentage of a group sum

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, group-by, average

I have this problem, in my report I have three groups (General, Department and details(users)) where I calculate the average performance of each user and with this the avg performance of each department, but when it comes to get the avg performance of the entire Org. the percentage does not match, I think is getting the avg value for each single user instead of the department group avg.

I need to get the value from the group and then do the avg. 
I have tried with:

Sum(Fields!Performance.Value, "GroupTotal")

But I get a error with the scope.

```
Performance

 - 0.00%
 - 14.97%
 - 16.04%
```

That is the column each row has another group inside with the values for each user

Hope I made myself clear, thanks!

Comment: What specific version of SSRS?

Comment: Post the expressions you are currently using and clarify the meaning of the data rows in your example.

Comment: This is the results I get, the below result in dark blue shoul be the AVG from the first grouping (light blue) it should be 63.42 but the results are wrong http://i60.tinypic.com/4hv9tz.png